# How to make $(".page-container > .page-host") right way?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
$("div .page-host") alert length 1
$(".page-container  .page-host") alert length 0
$(".page-container > .page-host") alert length 0
```

How to make it right ..?  I cant find the element.

```
<div class="page-container">
 Pub
    <div class="page-host">Sub</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something else is off see: http://jsfiddle.net/XaM62/

Comment: Only likely option is that the parent `div` does not really have a `class` attribute of `page-container`. There could be a typo. It could be an `id` and not a `class`. Many ways to get this wrong, but your code is valid.

Comment: Doesn't look bad, if you could reproduce in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)